# Is there any difference between changing basis of vectors and changing basis of matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra

Is there any difference between the changing the basis of vectors and changing the basis of matrices? To me what comes is suppose my coordinate is $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$. This appears common irrespective of vector/matrix. Another basis will be any $(x_1, y_1)$ and $(x_2, y_2)$, other than one of $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$. Now, on my coordinates, a point is $(5,7)$, then I need to transform it to $(x_1, y_1)$ and $(x_2, y_2)$ coordinates.

The [course](https://www.coursera.org/lecture/linear-algebra-machine-learning/matrices-changing-basis-q8iik) that I am following states: "The columns of a transformation matrix, are the axes of the new basis vectors of the mapping in my coordinate system." Any easy to understand explanation will be helpful.

Comment: I don't understand how this has to do with matrices. You are wanting to transform the coordinate $(5,7)$ in the $(1,0)$, $(0,1)$ basis into something in the $(x_1, y_1)$, $(x_2, y_2)$ basis? Am I understanding correctly? How are matrices involved here?

Comment: matrices represent linear maps between **two** vector spaces, therefore a matrix is given respect to **two** basis of vectors

Comment: Going through a lecture as part of course Mathematics for Machine Learning on Coursera: https://www.canva.com/design/DAE44DCQIas/Rf9Ji44XW2-VKkGS3MGzCw/view?utm_content=DAE44DCQIas&utm_campaign=designshare&utm_medium=link&utm_source=sharebutton  I have a slight doubt vector and matrix are treated synonymous there.https://www.coursera.org/learn/linear-algebra-machine-learning/lecture/q8iik/matrices-changing-basis

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand what your question is. Could you please try to clearify that?

Comment: @TechcosecLimited "Since by default, a matrix of two dimensions takes it granted (1,0), (0,1) coordinate" - What do you mean by "takes it granted"?

Comment: Okay, removing that.

Comment: While I can visualize changing basis of vectors, I have no clue what it will mean when it comes to changing basis of matrices. A matrix is a scalar quantity. So, direction or vector should not stand in its way!

Comment: @TechcosecLimited I have added an answer. If something is unclear, please let me know.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134295/discussion-between-techcosec-limited-and-filippo).

Answer (score 2):

> The course that I am following states: "The columns of a
> transformation matrix, are the axes of the new basis vectors of the
> mapping in my coordinate system."

I will explain what this exactly means:

In the following, I recommend that you think of vectors as arrows. As you know, we can take the sum of two arrows and we can multiply arrows with real numbers (scalar multiplication). More generally, let $V$ be a $n$-dimensional real vector space. In this context, a **coordinate system** is a linear bijection from $V$ to $\mathbb R^n$ or equivalently, a basis of $V$: If $\Phi\colon V\to\mathbb R^n$ is linear and bijective and $e_1,\ldots,e_n$ is the standard basis of $\mathbb R^n$, then $(\Phi^{-1}e_1,\ldots,\Phi^{-1}e_n)$ is a basis $V$ and conversely, if $v_1,\ldots,v_n$ is a basis of $V$, then the linear function $\Phi\colon V\to \mathbb R^n$ defined by $\Phi v_i=e_i$ is bijective.

Now suppose we have chosen a basis $(v_1,\ldots,v_n)$ of $V$ and $A\colon V\to V$ is a linear bijection. Then $A$ maps our basis to a new basis, i.e. $$(w_1,\ldots,w_n):=(Av_1,\ldots,Av_n)$$ is another basis of $V$. As explained above, the basis $v_1,\ldots,v_n$ induces a coordinate system $\Phi\colon V\to\mathbb R^n$ and we can consider the composition $$\Phi\circ A\circ\Phi^{-1}\colon\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^n$$
Since the composition is linear, we can identify it with a matrix $M\in \mathbb R^{n\times n}$ and as stated in your course, its columns are the axes of the new basis vectors of the mapping $A$ in our coordinate system $\Phi$, that is: $$M=(\Phi w{}_1|\cdots|\Phi w{}_n)$$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4395023/relating-dot-product-divided-with-square-of-the-vector-while-changing-basis-of-v  @Filippo It will help if you could answer the query.