# Relating dot product divided with square of the vector while changing basis of vector

Tags: linear-algebra

The lecture ([Mathematics for Machine Learning: Linear Algebra by Imperial College London](https://d3c33hcgiwev3.cloudfront.net/3pBFJJOuEemGqAqLppoP9A.processed/full/360p/index.mp4?Expires=1646438400&Signature=YJfgW67qaeBZpuuirZEUbA53pr4%7Ek3LzhCgxBpaIoEH-7qAvjzJ82kZedGp9cuWcwyS4Tb4hz9LDqAXNQGd9KhsUhounEwcsx4XEvakBiICoFeO15NN%7Eaa8nrCfIIy58VT29V0otxg-TP8RJ7bKjWQ2lCiKmcuRKDcK8yvPM7rI_&Key-Pair-Id=APKAJLTNE6QMUY6HBC5A)) covers changing basis of vectors. Finding difficult to follow how dot product r$_e $ b$_1$ /
$|b_1|^2 $ is used while changing basis.

Why dot product is divided by $|b_1|^2 $ to come to the conclusion that vector projection is 2 times b$_1$.

[image]

I think first solving the below problems will help in the process.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to know how the equation
$$r_b=\begin{pmatrix}\frac{r_e\cdot b_1}{|b_1|^2}\\\frac{r_e\cdot b_2}{|b_2|^2}\end{pmatrix}$$
can be derived. **However**, the notation is a bit sloppy and so the equation first needs to be interpreted correctly (part 1). Then we can think about its derivation (part 2).

### Part 1 - Interpretation

As already said, the notation is a bit sloppy and might confuse students that are new to the topic. Let me elaborate:

First of all, we need to clearify the setting that is implicitly considered in the video: We assume we are given a two-dimensional real [inner product space](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space) $V$, $r\in V$ and $e_1,e_2$ is an orthonormal basis of $V$. In addition, we consider a basis $b_1,b_2$ that was shown to be orthogonal in the video. In this context, we consider two inner product spaces - $V$ and $\mathbb R\times\mathbb R$ with the standard inner product - and hence the expression $v\cdot w$ is defined in two cases:

- $v$ and $w$ are both elements of $V$.
- $v$ and $w$ are both pairs of real numbers, i.e. elements of $\mathbb R\times\mathbb R$.

Thus, the expression $b_i\cdot r_e$ - the product of an element of $V$ and a pair of real numbers - is not defined. Here are two ways to fix the initial equation:
$$r_b=\begin{pmatrix}\frac{b_{1,e}\cdot r_e}{|b_1|^2}\\\frac{b_{2,e}\cdot r_e}{|b_2|^2}\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}\frac{b_{1}\cdot r}{|b_1|^2}\\\frac{b_{2}\cdot r}{|b_2|^2}\end{pmatrix}$$

### Part 2 - Derivation

To derive
$$r_{b,1}=\frac{b_1\cdot r}{b_1\cdot b_1}$$simply insert $$r=r_{b,1}b_1+r_{b,2}b_2$$on the RHS of the equation and use the fact that $b_1\cdot b_2=0$ (as shown in the video).

Comment: Still trying to understand. In addition to your reply, this thread (https://mathforums.com/threads/relating-dot-product-divided-with-square-of-the-vector-while-changing-basis-of-vector.362851/) is proving useful though need more effort

Comment: @TechcosecLimited I'm glad you found my answer useful :) If anything is unclear, let me know. You know, when learning math, it is impossible to always immediately understand everything. The key is to understand what exactly you don't understand and to ask good questions in the right places.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance. Trying to understand in parts. As mentioned by you "the product of an arrow and a pair of real numbers - is not defined". At the same time [2,1] - the coordinates of arrow and [3,4] - coordinates of line are dotted. That is, x components and y components are summed up. {(2x3) + (1x4)} = 10. How do I relate this 10 geometrically. Dot product is zero when two lines are perpendicular and 1 when two lines on the same plane or paralled. But in this case, 10.

Comment: (https://www.canva.com/design/DAE6GPo0iQk/mUY1qxk_C5AL8J4Uz8uYjg/view?utm_content=DAE6GPo0iQk&utm_campaign=designshare&utm_medium=link&utm_source=sharebutton

Comment: Given coordinates ON = [3,4] and O$a_1$ [2,1], how to deduce angle NOM. I guess dot product can help but not sure. (https://www.canva.com/design/DAE6GzfEbGo/f-dz9UdIRch3qrIjxtMSNg/view?utm_content=DAE6GzfEbGo&utm_campaign=designshare&utm_medium=link&utm_source=sharebutton)

Comment: @TechcosecLimited "Dot product is zero when two lines are perpendicular and 1 when two lines on the same plane or paralled. But in this case, 10" - No, if $v$ and $w$ point in the same direction, then $v\cdot w$ is simply the product of the length of $v$ and the length of $w$.

Comment: I have edited the first part of my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134594/discussion-between-filippo-and-techcosec-limited).